# RVM and different Ruby versions in ONE project

Tags: ruby

I would like to use different Rubys (ruby 1.9.3 and jruby 1.7.0) in one project.

I need to do this, because I am getting errors in my project, when I use Jruby for the whole project. Therefore, I want to use Jruby only for the classes that actually need it and normal Ruby for others.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby and JRuby can't run in the same process, so to use them together in the same project you need to have separate processes, and some kind of inter-process communication. This could be as simple as having the JRuby program execute a Ruby script using backticks, receiving stdout from the process as a string, or as much more complicated than that as it has to be. To get fancier, you could use a FIFO or a message queue, for instance.

Comment: Thank you very much! This will do it. I also found this nice tutorial on sub-processes in Ruby:http://devver.wordpress.com/2009/06/30/a-dozen-or-so-ways-to-start-sub-processes-in-ruby-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

You can't run one app instance with two different rubies. How do you think it would work? I see these options:

- run everything with ruby 1.9 (if possible and desirable);
- split the app and run one part with jruby and another with MRI.